# how to reloadData when tableview is in a subview of subview ViewCon

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `ViewController` which, has a `tableView` added as a subview, that is then embedded in a `UINavigationController` and then added as a subView to my `RootViewController` in my `ViewDidLoad` (of the `RootViewConroller`).

```
frontController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
frontController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[frontController.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

... ///

```
self.navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.frontController];

//finally add the Top UIViewController
 self.contentViewController = self.navBar;


/// Move to new view when cell is touched
     DetailsTwo *my_detailViewController = [[DetailsTwo alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsTwo" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

            [self.navBar pushViewController:my_detailViewController animated:YES];
```

My problem: How do I `[tableView reloadData]` the table View (When I go back to the view from the back button from navBar) ?

Why are both `ViewWillAppear` and `ViewDidAppear` not getting called (Conceptually what am I missing) ?

Hope that made sense and Thank You.

Comment: Shouldn't it be viewWillAppear?

Comment: Both do not get called:  I will update.

Comment: Whats your NavBar? is it navigation controller? Also can you post the code where you are moving to different vc ?

Comment: Yes NavBar is UINavigationController.

Comment: Implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and do the reload in `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`?

Comment: @jeffamaphone: Thanks but UINavigationControllerDelegate is new to me do you have an example or short description ?  I am currently looking\Goggling it now.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: Thanks for the help.  That put me on the right track - found the answer.  If you want the points just post your suggestions so I can check it .  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jeffamaphone - put me on the right track:  (hope this helps someone else)

```
//.h
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    UINavigationController *navController;
}

//.m
Then implement these two methods:

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
    willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [viewController viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
    didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [viewController viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

*****Be sure to set the root view controller as the delegate for the nav controller. Now viewWillAppear / viewDidAppear will be called whenever a controller is pushed/popped from the stack.